# How to set active links (navbar) in an async ufront app

Tags: haxe, ufront

I try to figure out how to set active links in a navbar or sitebar for an async ufront application.

On the server I can load and parse it dynamically inside the main (top level) controller via an api call like:

```
@inject public function init(context:HttpContext) {
    ufTrace("HomeController::init");

    var navStr:String = "";
    //getNavbar loads the navbar html snippet and parses the code to set 'active' some tags in relation to the request uri
    var navbarSurprise = siteApi.getNavbar(context.request.uri);
    navbarSurprise.handle(function (outcome) { 
        switch (outcome) {
            case Success(navbarStr): navStr = navbarStr;
            case Failure(err): navStr = "<h1>Could not load navigation: $err</h1>";
        }
    } );
    ViewResult.globalValues["navBar"] = navStr;

}
```

but that doesn't work on the client for pushstate urls. (navStr would always be empty)

The ViewResult.hx (line:126) doc states:
***Helpers (dynamic functions) can be included in your ViewResult also.***

Could this be a place to handle that?
But unfortunately I couldn't find any help/examples how to add helper functions to a ViewResult.

I was also thinking about doing it in a custom ViewEngine. But that seems a bit like overcomplicating things.

Any thoughts about that would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually I think the ***Helpers (dynamic functions)*** are ViewResult static extensions like e.g. .addJsScriptToResult(the.script.js). Although it would be possible to alter the response there, it is not very clean because I would have to add this to every result.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your are looking to render the navbar on the server when processing the request.

I did something like that some time ago by using sipple (another templating engine) but you can also use other engine (i think) like haxe template or erazor etc.

[This issue](https://github.com/ufront/ufront-mvc/issues/6) sums up how i processed different partials using [stipple](https://bitbucket.org/grumpytoad/stipple/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this work for you for asynchronous calls from the client as well? Perhaps I am wrong but I have the impression that my api call does (in a less elegant way and doesn't get the partial at compile time) the same thing . I just can't get in work in the controllers init function.

Comment: Yes the partials are loaded at compile time and rendered at runtime. I'm not sure what is wrong with your implementation, but i remember it is hard to get partials working with ufront using erazor, you can try switching to stipple as it provides better partial support.

Comment: In my example the application just never waits for the surprise outcome which is returned by my async api call. The same call works as expected inside a route function for example; but not in the init function. Could be it has something to do with the miniject problem in the actual ufront version ..!?

Comment: In that case I'm not sure, the easiest way would be to make it sync instead, if it has a negative impact on the app then you should discuss it with Jason Oneil he probably can give more advice.